# How to compare the content of the data columns with the list in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a data frame as follows:

| col1 | col2 | col3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | E | C |
| A |  | D |
| D | B |  |
| A | D | E |
| A |  | C |

And list `answer_key = ["A", "B", "C"]`.

I want to compare the values of each column to the list's value in sequence.

Returns the score based on the following rule: no responses = 0, successfully answered = 5, incorrectly answered = -5. Also, please return the entire score.

Comment: Did you forget to post the code you used to try to solve this? How about your expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
answer_key = np.array(["A", "B", "C"])
df['score'] = df.apply(lambda x: (pd.Series((x.to_numpy() == answer_key)).replace(False, -1).sum())*5 + len(x[x.isnull()])*5, axis=1)
```

OUTPUT:

```
  col1 col2 col3  score
0    A    E    C      5
1    A  NaN    D      0
2    D    B  NaN      0
3    A    D    E     -5
4    A  NaN    C     10
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate on this idea?

Comment: Sure, When you apply `lambda` with `axis = 1` it will give you each row as `Series`, convert that `Series` to `numpy array` and perform `element-wise` equal operation with `numpy` array of `answer_key`. It will give you a `boolean array`, sum that array and multiply with 5.

Comment: Thank you for your help; although, I still haven't found a solution to my problem. Perhaps I'll have to write a custom function. Example: `df.apply(my_func, axis=1)`

Comment: Oh sorry I think I missed `-5` part in your question. right?

Comment: Yes, no responses = 0, True = 5, False = -5

Comment: I think my answer just deals with `0` and `5` part. Give me sometime I will update my answer

Comment: Check my edited answer.

Comment: Thank you, I was able to write more clearly as a result of your suggestion:
`data["score"] = data.apply(lambda x: (x == answer_key).map({True: 5, False: -5}) + (x == "") * 5, axis=1
).sum(axis=1)`

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a homework question, so I will only provide you with pseudocode to help point you in the correct direction. I am also assuming that you are looking to compare the contents in each column to your answer_key and that these wont be dynamically added to.

```
# Create a list with your keys (you already did this)

# Create three separate lists for each column (col1, col2, col3)
# Also use something as a default value for values that are empty
# Ex1: col2 = ['E', None, 'B']
# Ex2: col2 = ['E', '0', 'B'] - either of these methods could work

# Create a dictionary to reference these list
cols = [0 : col1, 1 : col2, 2 : col3]

# Create an variable to store the entire score
score = 0

# Use nested loops to iterate through each column & each value
# example
for i in range(3):

    # temporarily cache a list object for referrence
    curList = cols.get(i)

    # Compare contents of the key and list
    for c in range(len(answer_key)):

        # If curList[c] == None (or whatever value you
        # are using for null) then score += 0

        # If answer_key[c] == curList[c] then score += 5
        # Else if answer_key[c] != curList[c] then score -= 5
```

Comment: Thank you; I'd want to use pandas to solve the problem (if available)